# What are the side effects of long term Cryo Sleep?

Tags: science-in-society

I am writing a film about a group of people who wake up from cryosleep after 5-10 years. I would like to know what kind of side effects these people would have upon awakening.
I've tried googling, but haven't found anything other than some sort of cold burn, chill, and confusion.
Also, one of the side effects that are crucial to the movie is memory loss, but I'm not sure if that could be scientifically possible or would be considered as sci-fi.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as we know, the only notable side effect of long (or even short) term cryo sleep is death; and unfortunately, that undesirable side effect happens with 100% certainty. If in your world freezing a person does not result in their death, then what side effects are there is entirely up to you. They may wake up with headaches; they may wake up with vertigo; or with hives; they may stutter after waking up, the stuttering becoming more and more noticeable as they are frozen and thawed repeatedly; they may wake up horny, or, on the contrary, with reduced libido; their eyes may change color; &c.

Comment: As @AlexP stated, if "cryosleep" means actually freezing a person then the question translates to "After ice crystals form in every cell of the body and rupture the cell membranes, when I defrost the dead body and use techno-magic to repair the cellular damage then what are the side effects?"  The problem is that we currently not only can't do the techno-magic, we can't think of an approach to do it. Hence no idea of possible side-effects for a currently unimaginable process. ("Repair nanites" get mentioned, which here means "techno-magic".)

Comment: You need to provide details about cryosleep technology: How people get frozen and how they are revived. These procedures will determine side effects.

Comment: VTC as Needs details or clarity. This question is not opinion-based if enough details about cryosleep technology are provided.

Comment: If you don't have (say you're not a scientifically minded person) a technologically original way to do this yourself, then why not ask about the various tropes in book and film which deal with this. The best place for that might be [scifi.se] our sister site, you can then construct a more definitively answerable question here.

Comment: I'm the last close voter, let me explain why. You couldn't find anything via Google because no one's ever done it to a human. Oh, we've frozen people - who are either already dead or terminally ill, but we've never awakened them. We're not even sure if we can. Therefore, any answer just a SWAG. With no way to objectively choose a best answer, the question is opinion-based. Also, [tag:science-in-society] is inappropriately used as you have not asked a question about "the use and perception of science by the inhabitants of a fictional world."

Comment: BUT!!! Having said that, I'd like to invite you to ask this question again, but this time use the [tag:science-based] tag and link to [elemtilas' answer to my Meta Q about the science-based tag](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8366/40609) and ask for a [finite list of scientifically-based but not necessarily scientifically-restricted ideas](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609) about what such people *could* encounter. State that the best answer will justify its suggestions with the greatest amount of science.

Comment: NOTE: To avoid having your new question closed as a duplicate, [edit] *this question* to conform to what I just suggested. That automatically puts it in the reopen queue. I'd happily VTR with the suggested changes. (And hopefully @AlexP will thumbs-up that effort. He's not wrong, he's just pointing out what we know to be true *today.* But that's boring...  )

Comment: OK, one more thing... I do NOT believe you need to provide details about how your cryofreeze works. Sheesh, people... Specifically state in your question that "how" the freezing process works is not part of the question. You're only interested in the possible consequences of being thawed out after a specified period of time. We're being a bit nit-picky asking you to invent tech that doesn't actually exist today.

Comment: The OP might also be better off eliminating the term 'Cryo' and just calling it 'suspended animation'. That removes all references to the 'how can one be frozen for that long' issue, and allow more general but undefined techniques such as extreme low-metabolic low-temperature chemically-induced methods. that do not destroy tissue. See https://www.popsci.com/will-we-be-able-to-bring-cryogenically-frozen-corpses-back-to-life/ for a list of problems and solutions or https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4620520/ for memory effects.

Answer (score 4):

Zombies. They would be zombies. Their soul would have believed the body were dead, and would have left it behind. Then these soul-less bodies would 'thaw out wake up' and be true human-less-body zombies.

Or not.

Comment: I'd watch that movie.

Comment: @SurpriseDog Spoiler alert the souls are convinced to return to the bodies, if only temporarily, and the Earth is saved

Answer (score 3):

**They are better than they were, and they are different than they were.**

People wake up sick and drunk and weak and stumble around.  That is fine as far as it goes.  But let us consider the Stallone and Snipes film [Demolition Man] which had a different take on cryosleep.
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demolition_Man_(film)).  In this film the good guy (Spartan) and bad guy (Phoenix) were both frozen in cryosleep, and their mind and bodies worked on by computers while they were unconscious.

> Spartan and Huxley witness this exchange on security cameras and
> review the cryo-prison records. They discover that Phoenix's
> rehabilitation program was tailored by Cocteau to make him even more
> dangerous than he was in 1996, including martial arts, computer
> hacking, knowledge of torture techniques, and murderous impulses; by
> contrast, Spartan's program taught him to knit and sew.

Both men are surprised at the changes.  Stallone's character occupies himself sewing at several points during the movie.

In your fiction, the sleep pod exercises the body and the mind.  The problem is that the characters were supposed to sleep for 18 months, but it went on much longer than expected.  The mind exercise program has overwritten some old memories and skills with new things.  Some of these things used to belong to other people and maybe some things that belonged to other characters.

All the characters know all the lyrics to a lot of songs which they do not realize until one starts singing, and they all start singing.  They sound great together even though none of them understand the language that these songs are in.